# SQL Server - how to "Generate and Publish Scripts" automatically

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to automatically (ideally from the command prompt in a batch file) automate the generation of the schema of my SQL Server 2008 R2 database.

In SSMS, I can right-click the DB, choose "Tasks", "Generate scripts", and then follow the wizard to gen a Schema script. Is there a command-line version of this process that I can use?

Comment: I think SQL Server is a great piece of software, but I absolutely loathe its supporting tools for their lack of common-sense features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695738/programmatically-generate-script-for-all-objects-in-a-database/1695743#1695743), there appear to be tools called [SMOScript](http://www.devio.at/index.php/smoscript) and [ScriptDB](http://scriptdb.codeplex.com/) that can do that.

If you find a way without third party tools please share :)

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft released a new tool a few weeks ago called mssql-scripter that's the command line version of the "Generate Scripts" wizard in SSMS. It's a Python-based, open source command line tool and you can find the official announcement [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dataplatforminsider/2017/05/17/try-new-sql-server-command-line-tools-to-generate-t-sql-scripts-and-monitor-dynamic-management-views/). Essentially, the scripter allows you to generate a T-SQL script for your database/database object as a .sql file. You can generate the file and then execute it. This might be a nice solution for you to generate the schema of your db (schema is the default option). Here's a quick usage example to get you started:

```
$ pip install mssql-scripter
# script the database schema and data piped to a file.
$ mssql-scripter -S localhost -d AdventureWorks -U sa  > ./adventureworks.sql
```

More usage examples are on our GitHub page here: https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-xplat-cli/blob/dev/doc/usage_guide.md