# Programatically back up to sql file

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, vb.net

In Visual Studio I can export an entire database with all its data, schema, etc..., to a **.sql dump file** using the "Publish to provider" option. Is there a way to generate that file with C# or VB.NET?

Comment: It is generally a bad idea to backup everything to text format. Schema - perhaps, but not data.

Comment: Are you looking to back up your DB as a regular .BAK file, or do you want it as DDL and DML statements that would recreate the DB?

Comment: @Jim, I would like to back up by db to an .sql file.

Comment: Ok, so you want DDL and DML statements that would recreate your schema and data...

Comment: @Jim, I don't know what DDL and MDL statement means, but yes, I need an sql dump file, such as in mysql.

Comment: DDL - Data Definition Language (CREATE, DROP, etc). DML - Data Manipulation Language (SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE, etc).

Comment: Why do you want it? This appears to be a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Are you trying to move the data from SqlServer to MySql or something? There are other (easier) ways to do it than generating a sql dump file.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with this code,

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = "Cmd.exe";
psi.Arguments = "/C sqlcmd -S servername -E -Q " + 
                "\"BACKUP DATABASE [dbname] TO  DISK = " + 
                "N'D:\\TEMP\\test.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, INIT,  " + 
                "NAME = N'dbname-Complete Backup', " + 
                "SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10\"";

Process.Start(psi);
```

Of course you need to replace the `servername` with the name of your server, `dbname` with the name of your database and the destination file name (`d:\temp\test.bak`) with your preferred output name.
At the end you will have a file with a complete backup of your database. You can restore this file only on the same or newer version of Sql Server

Comment: Thnx, but I need a .sql file, not .bak

Comment: @Steve, from the comments it seems he doesn't want a .BAK file, but instead wants it all dumped to DDL/DML statements, like if you were to use "Script As" in SSMS.

Comment: @Jim I see, but if I look at this [old  article](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/scripting-database-objects-using-smo-updated) this task will be  complex and I am not sure if really Worth the effort required.

Answer (score 1):

SQL SMO can be an option for you, I used it long back for schema generation, have a look at [this](http://www.techbubbles.com/sql-server/creating-sql-server-database-objects-backup-using-smo/) , though it initially says only schema it later refers to an option of including scripting of data as well where it says:-

```
If you want to include the data as well in the script then write
options.ScriptData = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a number of different backup operations using sqlcmd.  For instance, to get a .BAK file you can run the following from a batch file or command line...

```
sqlcmd -S host\DBName -E -Q "BACKUP DATABASE [Name_of_Database] TO DISK=’X:PathToBackupLocation[Name_of_Database].bak’"
```

*EDIT

Since OP seems to be looking for DDL and DML to recreate the DB, and not a .BAK file, the above isn't what he needs, but I'll leave it here in case it helps anyone else.

To get to the OP's needs though, you'll probably want to check out the SMO library.

See also these SO posts...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1162348/1246574

[Programmatically generate script for all objects in a database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1695738/1246574)

Comment: That won't backup anything.

Comment: @Sam, would you care to elaborate?  I copied this directly out of a script that I use in production to create daily DB backups, so I fail to see how it "won't backup anything".

Comment: If you run THAT SCRIPT, it will not create a backup.  You stated it would.  -S is server name, -E is integrated auth, -Q is the query.  "Enter Description Here" is not a query.