# VBA method to generate sql script from MS SQL

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel worksheet where I can insert Data into a MS SQL Database.
When closing this worksheet, a mail with the sql-script attached should be generated and send automatically. The script includes all the create table, sequences and insert statements.

I can generate the sql script manually in the MS SQL Studio, but maybe there´s a method (here: *generate_sql_script*) to generate the script automatically.

Here´s my code for generating the mail:

```
Dim objOutlook, objMail, sql_Script As Object
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

sql_Script = generate_sql_script

With objMail
    .To = "myEmail@test.com"
    .Subject = "new sql script attached"
    .Body = "Dear Sir or madam..."
    .Attachments.Add sql_Script
    .Send
End With
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Are you talking about MS SQL? So tag your question correctly and remove the MySql tag

Comment: How are you expecting to generate this **"sqp-script"**?

Comment: @TrevorD nothing really. I tried to "record the macro" in Excel, but it didn´t work. I don´t know if my idea of writing a method, that generates the script for me is even possible.

Comment: @nacho yes I´m talking about MS SQL.. sorry for the mistake.

Comment: @Zac THAT´S my question.

Comment: What generated the SQL script in the first place?  Does it create a text file or .sql file you can read?

Comment: @TrevorD the sql script includes all the create table, create sequence and insert statements to create the database completely new. When create the script manually I proceed this way: *in MS SQL Server Management Studio* -> select the database -> rights click on the database -> select *Tasks* -> select *generating script* -> continue the procedure and make sure you generate the scheme **and** the data. Result will be a .sql script

Comment: @TrevorD I have this database twice. one is only for tests. And when the tests are sucessfully I thinks it´s easier to create the database completelly new instead of writing all the *update statements*. It is a very small database..

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695738/programmatically-generate-script-for-all-objects-in-a-database

Does that question help you?

Comment: This is `SQL Server` isn't it?  Getting confused with the `MS SQL` and `MS SQL Studio` references.  Maybe add the tag for it?

Comment: I'm extremely doubtful this type of SQL-integration functionality exists in Excel.